# PyQt5 QMainWindow, QDockWidget, fitting autosize with screensize

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qmainwindow, qdockwidget

I've created a`QMainWindow` with menubar and 4 `dockable widgets`. First dockwidget contents `multipletabs`, second is `Qpainter widget`, third is `Matlabplot` and fourth is `pdf report`.

When I run the code shows up like this below.

[image]

I want to be like below.

[image]

I want to divide screen into four widget automatically whenever it runs at any screen, And I want to have tabs to resize to its content.

Or do you have any better idea of having such widget, you are welcome to come with it.

**Update of code**

Resize of Qdockwidget brings this post forward. It seems that Qt Qdockwidget resize has been an issue for long time ago. I find it very difficult to program my Qmainwindow with 4 Qdockwidget, which the dock would fit and resize according to its contents, with other words, child widget. and According to Qt documentation, Qdockwidget resizes and respect the size of child Widgets. to get straight to problem, my mainwindow has 4 qdockwidgets, I would like to have them resizable according to contents.

What I have tried and used so far. 
I have used following size functions.

```
self.sizeHint, self.minimumSize(), self.maximumSize() and self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint()).
```

I am able to fix the size of contents in first Qdockwidget by using following codes.

```
self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())
```

Above code is written in the child widgets `Class widgets`
But that is not enough in order to work it, despite following codes needed to run and effect.

```
    self.first.setMinimumSize(self.first.sizeHint())
    self.grid.setMinimumSize(self.grid.sizeHint())
    self.third.setMinimumSize(self.third.sizeHint())
    self.adjustSize()
    self.first.setMinimumSize(self.first.minimumSizeHint())
    self.grid.setMinimumSize(self.grid.minimumSizeHint())
    self.third.setMinimumSize(self.third.minimumSizeHint())
```

Noting that still my dockwindow does not resize according to child widgets. Dockwidget expand and increase. One may ask, Qdockwidgets could arrange and control by `resizeDocks()`. This code line is used and tried, but still does not get the desired behaviour.

I have been looking around and could find some relevant questions.

[C++ resize a docked Qt QDockWidget programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722939/c-resize-a-docked-qt-qdockwidget-programmatically)

[Forcing a QDockWidget to behave like a central widget when it comes to resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606699/forcing-a-qdockwidget-to-behave-like-a-central-widget-when-it-comes-to-resizing?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Create a QDockWidget that resizes to it's contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286646/create-a-qdockwidget-that-resizes-to-its-contents?rq=1)

Those questions do not solve my problem.

**Visualization of my code launch**

1- When code runs and display on screen.

[image]

2- Desired and wanted display by first run of software.

[image]

3- When user tabs between tabwidgets want to resize to its content as image below.

[image]

4- The code is given below.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, 
QDesktopWidget, QApplication, QAction, QFileDialog,QColorDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QMessageBox, QDockWidget, 
QTabWidget, QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QFrame, QSplitter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QRadioButton, QListWidget, 
QCheckBox, QTextEdit, QDialog, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QFileInfo, QFile
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QKeySequence, QPainter, QPalette, QPen, 
QBrush, QTextCursor, QFont

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plt.style.use('ggplot')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import seaborn as sns


iconroot = os.path.dirname(__file__)

class mywindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(1200,800))
        self.setWindowTitle('My Graphic Window')

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        centralWidget.setLayout(gridLayout)

        qtRectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())


        imageroot = QFileInfo(__file__).absolutePath()

        # Greate new action
        newaction = QAction(QIcon(imageroot +'/images/new.png'), '&New', self)
        newaction.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        newaction.setStatusTip('New document')
        newaction.triggered.connect(self.newCall) 


        # Greate menu bar and add action
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        filemenu = menubar.addMenu('&Test')
        filemenu.addAction(newaction)


        # Get current screen geometry
        self.Screen = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        print(self.Screen, self.Screen.height(), self.Screen.width())


#    def createToolbar(self):
        self.filetoolbar = self.addToolBar('File')
        self.filetoolbar.addAction(newaction)


        self.topleftdockwindow()
        self.toprightdockwindow()



    def newCall(self):
        print('New')


    # Greate dockable subwindow. 

    def topleftdockwindow(self):
        topleftwindow = QDockWidget ('Info',self)
        # Stick window to left or right
        topleftwindow.setAllowedAreas(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)

        self.addDockWidget(Qt.TopDockWidgetArea, topleftwindow)

        topleftwindow.setWidget(createtabwidget())
        topleftwindow.resize( topleftwindow.minimumSize() )

        bottomleftwindow = QDockWidget("Matplot",self)
        bottomleftwindow.setAllowedAreas(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, bottomleftwindow)
        bottomleftwindow.setWidget(createplotwidget())
        self.setDockNestingEnabled(True)     
        topleftwindow.resize( topleftwindow.minimumSize() )

        self.splitDockWidget(topleftwindow, bottomleftwindow , Qt.Vertical)
        #self.resizeDocks((topleftwindow, bottomleftwindow), (40,20), 
#Qt.Horizontal)


        # Greate topright dockwindow. 

    def toprightdockwindow(self):
        toprightdock = QDockWidget ('Plot',self)
        toprightdock = QDockWidget ('Plot',self)
        toprightdock.setAllowedAreas(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.TopDockWidgetArea, toprightdock)
        #self.setDockOptions(self.AnimatedDocks | self.AllowNestedDocks)
        toprightdock.setWidget(createpaintwidget())
        toprightdock.setFloating( True )
        bottomrightdock = QDockWidget("Technical report",self)
        bottomrightdock.setAllowedAreas(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, bottomrightdock)  
        bottomrightdock.setWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget())
        self.splitDockWidget(toprightdock, bottomrightdock, Qt.Vertical)




class createpaintwidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()      
        self.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Base)       
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.sizeHint()
        self.adjustSize()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.pen = QPen()
        self.brush = QBrush(Qt.gray,Qt.Dense7Pattern)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.setBrush(self.brush)
        painter.drawRect(100,100,250,250)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush())
        painter.drawEllipse(400,100,200,200)


class createplotwidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initializewidget()
        self.plot1()
        self.setMaximumSize(self.sizeHint())
        self.adjustSize()    

    def initializewidget(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Plotting M&N")
        gridlayout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(gridlayout)

        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas,self)
        gridlayout.addWidget(self.canvas,1,0,1,2)
        gridlayout.addWidget(self.toolbar,0,0,1,2)


    def plot1(self):
 #        sns.set()
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        x = [i for i in range(100)]
        y = [i**2 for i in x]
        ax.plot(x,y, 'b.-')
        ax.set_title('Quadratic Plot')
        self.canvas.draw()



class createtextdocument(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.textedit()

    def textedit(self):        
        self.textedit = QTextEdit()
        self.cursor = self.textedit.textCursor()


class createtabwidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Greate tabs in dockable window        
        tab = QTabWidget()

        scroll = QScrollArea()
        ncroll = QScrollArea()
        mcroll = QScrollArea()
        self.first = firsttabgeometry()
        self.grid = Grid()
        self.third = thirdtabloads()

        scroll.setWidget(self.first)
        ncroll.setWidget(self.grid)
        mcroll.setWidget(self.third)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.first.setMinimumSize(self.first.sizeHint())
        self.grid.setMinimumSize(self.grid.sizeHint())
        self.third.setMinimumSize(self.third.sizeHint())
        self.adjustSize()
        self.first.setMinimumSize(self.first.minimumSizeHint())
        self.grid.setMinimumSize(self.grid.minimumSizeHint())
        self.third.setMinimumSize(self.third.minimumSizeHint())

        # Adding multiple tabslides         
        tab.addTab(self.first,'One')
        tab.addTab(self.grid,'Two')
        tab.addTab(self.third,'Three')
        tab.setFont(QFont("Georgia",10,QFont.Normal))

        vboxlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vboxlayout.addWidget(tab)
        self.setLayout(vboxlayout)


class firsttabgeometry(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())

        iconroot = QFileInfo(__file__).absolutePath()
        font = QFont("Georgia",10,QFont.Normal)

        # Add widget and buttons to tabs
        sectiontypegroupbox = QGroupBox('&One',self)
        sectiontypegroupbox.setFont(QFont("Georgia",10,QFont.Normal))

        tab1button = QPushButton('')
        tab1button.setIcon(QIcon(iconroot +'/images/circularcolumn'))
        tab1button.setIconSize(QSize(60,60))
        tab1button.clicked.connect(self.One)


        squarebutton = QPushButton('')
        squarebutton.setIcon(QIcon(iconroot +'/images/squarecolumn'))
        squarebutton.setIconSize(QSize(60,60))
        squarebutton.clicked.connect(self.Two)

        wallbutton = QPushButton("")
        wallbutton.setIcon(QIcon(iconroot +'/images/wall'))
        wallbutton.setIconSize(QSize(60,60))
        wallbutton.clicked.connect(self.Three)


        circularlabel = QLabel("    One",self)




    circularlabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        circularlabel.setFont(font)
        sclabel = QLabel("    Two",self)
        sclabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sclabel.setFont(font)

        walllabel = QLabel("    Three",self)
        walllabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        walllabel.setFont(font)


        bottomgroupbox = QGroupBox("Group 2")
        vboxlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        vboxlayout.addStretch()
        radiobutton2 = QRadioButton("Radio Button")
        radiobutton3 = QRadioButton("Radio Button")
        testbutton2 = QPushButton('Test Button 2')
        vboxlayout.addWidget(radiobutton2)
        vboxlayout.addWidget(radiobutton3)
        vboxlayout.addWidget(testbutton2)


        bottomgroupbox.setLayout(vboxlayout)      

        mainlayout = QGridLayout()

        mainlayout.addWidget(tab1button,0,0)
        mainlayout.addWidget(circularlabel,0,1)
        mainlayout.addWidget(squarebutton,1,0)
        mainlayout.addWidget(sclabel,1,1)
        mainlayout.addWidget(wallbutton,2,0)
        mainlayout.addWidget(walllabel,2,1)
        mainlayout.setContentsMargins(200,50,50,50)
        sectiontypegroupbox.setLayout(mainlayout)

        gridlayout = QGridLayout()
        gridlayout.addWidget(sectiontypegroupbox,1,0)
        gridlayout.setContentsMargins(25,25,25,25)
        self.setLayout(gridlayout)


    def One(self):
        print('One')

    def Two(self):
        print('Two')

    def Three(self):
        print('Three')


class FooWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, path_icon, text, checked=False, parent=None):
        super(FooWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(iconroot, path_icon))
        pixmap_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        pixmap_label.resize(150, 150)
        pixmap_label.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(pixmap_label.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

        text_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(text)
        checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(checked=checked)

        lay.addWidget(pixmap_label)
        lay.addWidget(text_label)
        lay.addWidget(checkbox)


class Grid(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Grid, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())
        font = QFont("Georgia",8,QFont.Normal)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        icons = ["images/fixed-fixed.png", 
                 "images/pinned-pinned.png",
                 "images/fixed-free.png",
                 "images/fixed-pinned.png"]

        texts = ["Ley = 1.0 L\nLec = 1.0 L",
             "Ley = 0.699 L\nLec = 0.699 L",
             "Ley = 2.0 L\nLec = 2.0 L",
             "Ley = 0.5 L\nLec = 0.5 L"]

        for path_icon, text in zip(icons, texts):
            w = FooWidget(os.path.join(iconroot, path_icon), text)
            lay.addWidget(w)



class thirdtabloads(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(thirdtabloads, self).__init__(parent)     
        self.adjustSize()
        table = loadtable()


        add_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add")
        add_button.clicked.connect(table._addrow)

        delete_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Delete")
        delete_button.clicked.connect(table._removerow)

        copy_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Copy")
        copy_button.clicked.connect(table._copyrow)

        button_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        button_layout.addWidget(add_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        button_layout.addWidget(delete_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        button_layout.addWidget(copy_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop )

        tablehbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        tablehbox.setContentsMargins(10,10,10,10)
        tablehbox.addWidget(table)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addLayout(button_layout, 0, 1)
        grid.addLayout(tablehbox, 0, 0) 


def copy_widget(w):
    if isinstance(w, QtWidgets.QWidget):
        new_w = type(w)()
        if isinstance(w, QtWidgets.QComboBox):
            vals = [w.itemText(ix) for ix in range(w.count())]
            new_w.addItems(vals)
        return new_w


class loadtable(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(loadtable, self).__init__(1, 5, parent)

        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))   
        headertitle = ("Load Name","N [kN]","My [kNm]","Mz [kNm]","Load Type")
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headertitle)

        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)



   self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
        self.setColumnWidth(0, 130)

        combox_lay = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        combox_lay.addItems(["ULS","SLS"])
        self.setCellWidget(0, 4, combox_lay)


        self.cellChanged.connect(self._cellclicked)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def _cellclicked(self, r, c):
        it = self.item(r, c)
        it.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def _addrow(self):
        rowcount = self.rowCount()
        self.insertRow(rowcount)
        combox_add = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        combox_add.addItems(["ULS","SLS"])
        self.setCellWidget(rowcount, 4, combox_add)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def _removerow(self):
        if self.rowCount() > 0:
            self.removeRow(self.rowCount()-1)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def _copyrow(self):
        r = self.currentRow()
        if 0 <= r < self.rowCount():
            cells = {"items": [], "widgets": []}
            for i in range(self.columnCount()):
                it = self.item(r, i)
                if it:
                    cells["items"].append((i, it.clone()))
                w = self.cellWidget(r, i)
                if w:
                    cells["widgets"].append((i, copy_widget(w)))
            self.copy(cells, r+1)

    def copy(self, cells, r):
        self.insertRow(r)
        for i, it in cells["items"]:
            self.setItem(r, i, it)
        for i, w in cells["widgets"]:
            self.setCellWidget(r, i, w)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    mainWin = mywindow()
    mainWin.show()
    mainWin.showMaximized()  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would appreciate much any help on this.

Comment: One tool that I found really useful while solving these types of problems was PyQt designer http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html . Generally what I did was make whatever minimalistic functionality I wanted, generated the python script, and borrowed the code.

Comment: I do not use PyQT designer yet, I have just written all codes above. But your point makes sense. I maybe try it. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem under ubuntu 20.04 and python 3.6. If I add a dummy dock widget with the sizes I like to have (using setMaximumSize), and remove if by a singleshot QTimer action, the size of the dock widgets don't changed again. Additionally, there exists a method resizeDocks, but a far as I understand this method is used to set the relative size of docks in the same area, not the size of docks in different areas

Comment: My best advice is to drop dock widget, they wont work as they should. You may use Qsplitter as answer to the question. Do not use time on Qdock widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If floating windows aren't essential to your tool then you can try dropping `QDockWidget` and using a series of `QSplitter` instead. This way you can have your nice box layout while having tabs to resize horizontally and vertically, and still resizing properly when the tool as a whole resizes.

My example is in `PySide2`, but you'll probably need to do very minor tweaks to `PyQt5` (probably just the import names):

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class SubWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, label, parent=None):
        super(SubWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(label, parent=self)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font-size:40px;}")

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.sub_win_1 = SubWindow("1", parent=self)
        self.sub_win_2 = SubWindow("2", parent=self)
        self.sub_win_3 = SubWindow("3", parent=self)
        self.sub_win_4 = SubWindow("4", parent=self)

        self.sub_splitter_1 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent=self)
        self.sub_splitter_1.addWidget(self.sub_win_1)
        self.sub_splitter_1.addWidget(self.sub_win_2)

        self.sub_splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent=self)
        self.sub_splitter_2.addWidget(self.sub_win_3)
        self.sub_splitter_2.addWidget(self.sub_win_4)

        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical, parent=self)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.sub_splitter_1)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.sub_splitter_2)

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Layout example")
        self.resize(500, 500)


inst = MainWindow()
inst.show()
```

This gives you something like this:

[image]

Right now the top/bottom horizontal splitters function separately, but you can easily tie them together with an event.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have reached to point to quit floating `Qdockwidget` design, instead using `Qsplitter`. Which I have already begun on it. Thanks and I would mark your answer as alternativ design.

Comment: Ah well at least it gives you some validation that you took a good alternative :)